# How to pass blank value to date parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure with 3 parameters. Everything works well until I execute procedure with month or week or day (e.g. '2020-07-27'). When I pass '0' as @DateDay parameter then as a result I have got a bunch of records (all from  year 2020). What I would like to return is 0 records.  This is my query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc]

@DateDay VARCHAR,
@DateWeek INT,
@DateMonth INT

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Year INT = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())

SELECT
o.OrderNr,
c.CustomerName


FROM [dbo].Orders o
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customer c on o.OrderID=c.CustomerID

WHERE
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR,o.CreateDate,23)=@DateDay OR @DateDay='0') AND 
    (MONTH(o.CreateDate)=@DateMonth OR @DateMonth=0) AND
    (DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,o.CreateDate)=@DateWeek OR @DateWeek=0) AND
    DATEPART(YEAR,o.CreateDate)=@Year

END
GO
```

To be more precise, when execute this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[proc] '0',0,5
```

I got all records for May. When I execute this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[proc] '0',29,0
```

I got all records for 29th week. When I execute this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[proc] '0',0,0
```

I got all records for 2020. I would like to got in return 0 records since I don't pass any date values. What's wrong with my query and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Then remove the "OR @DateDay='0' " part?

Comment: Dates aren't strings and have no format, they're binary values. What you're doing will always fail one way or another and *always* ignore indexes. Use the *correct* type for the job. For dates, use one of the date types like `date`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`

Comment: Catch-all queries are bad for performance too although in this case the query won't use any indexes and perform a full table scan due to all the conversions applied on `o.CreatedDate`.

Comment: First of all, why do you pass Week and Month as int and Day as char? I would suggest to pass all parameters as int. This done, you can easily extend your WHERE clause by `WHERE @DateDay + @DateWeek + @DateMonth > 0 AND (--> Your WHERE CLAUSE here...)`

Comment: @Tyron78 that would be as bad as the original  - the query would still perform a full table scan. The OP tried to do something "clever" and use the same query to filter by a full date, month or year, even though this would result in *very* different execution plans.

Comment: The *easy* and *fast* way to fix this query is to use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) (a heavily indexed table with dates for the next eg 20 years, with explicit Year, Month, Semester, Day of Month, Day of Week etc), join with it and filter on the field you want directly. This way you can easily query for any period you want taking full advantage of indexes without *any* conversions

Comment: In your case, when you pass '0',0,0 then your first 3 where conditions are getting true but don't get any records based on these 3 conditions and records are fetched based on your last year condition. You can put an if condition above select query and below Year declaration like below:
`If @DateDay = '0' AND @DateWeek = 0 And @DateMonth = 0
Begin
    Set @Year = 0
End`

Comment: I pass DateDay as CHAR because I pass the whole day as parameter, I mean '2020-07-27'. I don't pass day number itself but whole date. I used DATE type for DateDay but I got some warning when executed with ```OR @DateDay = '0'``` in WHERE

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use your solution now. I have a Calendar table with all those explicit elments but the problem is that o.CreateDate is of DATETIME type. Calendar table only have DATE type dates (without hrs, just date). WHen I join o.CreateDate with Calendar.Date field then they don't match at all. So what I need to do is using CONVERT(DATE,o.CreateDate) on join. Query executes fast and returns proper output but is it a good solution? How can I avoid cenverting o.CreateDate on join?

Comment: Does `CreatedDate` contain a time part? If not, you can join directly. Otherwise you can use `cast(createdate as date)`. This can take advantage of indexes although it's not optimal. If you care about years and months though it would be better to create a separate column that actually contains a date not a datetime

Comment: @Muska in any case, the big bug is passing a date as a string. Change `@ DateDay` to `date` and pass `NULL` if you don't want to specify a value

Answer (score 1):

This is broken:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc] (
    @DateDay VARCHAR,
-------------^
    @DateWeek INT,
    @DateMonth INT
)
```

In SQL Server, always include a length parameter with string declarations.  The default varies by context; and in this case, you have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc] (
    @DateDay VARCHAR(1),
    @DateWeek INT,
    @DateMonth INT
)
```

I *might* suggest a longer string:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc] (
    @DateDay VARCHAR(255),
    @DateWeek INT,
    @DateMonth INT
)
```

But you seem to be using this for a *date* comparison.  So, pass in a `date`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc] (
    @DateDay DATE,
    @DateWeek INT,
    @DateMonth INT
)
```

And then use `NULL` as the wildcard.

To fix your actual problem, you need special logic to handle the "all being zero" case:

```
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),o.CreateDate,23) = @DateDay OR @DateDay = '0') AND 
      (MONTH(o.CreateDate)=@DateMonth OR @DateMonth=0) AND
      (DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, o.CreateDate) = @DateWeek OR @DateWeek = 0) AND
      DATEPART(YEAR, o.CreateDate) = @Year AND
      (@DateDay <> '0' OR @DateMonth <> 0 OR @DateWeek <> 0)
```

This would look different using a `DATE` and `NULL`s.

Comment: seems tricky, btw I tried with NULL and with DATE as data type, I'll check out if it works tomorrow at work

Comment: I used DATE type  but it doesn't work, I got error: Error converting data type varchar to date.

Comment: @Muska whatever string you passed doesn't match the server's locale, so it can't be parsed back to a date. You'll always have that problem if you pass dates as strings instead of the correct type, ie `date` in this case or `datetime`, `datetime2` etc